# Finding movies with more male actors than females SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to learn PostgreSQL with the imdb database and I can't seem to figure out how to list out the movies with more male actors than female.

I have three tables to work with

1. Table movie with movie_id, movie_title, movie_year
2. Table actor with actor_id, actor_name, actor_gender
   (The gender can be either 'M' or 'F')
3. Table movie_cast with actor_id and movie_id

Can someone point me in the right direction to how to approach problems like this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The right direction would be to Google for a SQL basics website or read a book on the same subject. We could write a ready query for you but that would not help you in learning.

Comment: JOIN, GROUP BY, SUM(), CASE, HAVING with these keywords you can answer the question. Show us what you tried so far.

Comment: @Gabriel I was not aware of CASE until now. I'll have a read and try it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the query below.

```
Select T1.movie_title as movie_title 
from movie T1
join movie_cast T2
on T1.movie_id = T2.movie_id
join actor T3
on T2.actor_id = T3.actor_id
group by T1.movie_title
having sum(case when T3.actor_gender = 'M' then 1 else 0 end) > sum(case when T3.actor_gender = 'F' then 1 else 0 end);
```

The idea here is to compare aggregates using having clause.